# Two iphones, one in the US and one in Mexico

Tags: iphone

I set up two stage verification on my US iphone with the security code and evrything.
Now, i tried to do the same thing on my Mexican phone, but it won't accept the code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5593) you have to have one of the following carriers in Mexico.

Lusacell

Movistar

Nextel

Telcel

SMS delivery of verification codes currently works in Mexico with the named wireless carriers.